# MongoDB permission changes?

Tags: java, mongodb

I used to use MongoClient#isLocked() to check if the authentication succeed seeing as I didn't find any way of checking if I am connected and authorized.
Today, I found out that this code is erroring Code 13 not Authorized. I didn't change anything and it also worked like that before. I know that this method is deprecated but I didn't find any other way of checking if the Client is connected. I didn't update anything so i'm quite confused of why it doesn't happen to work anymore.
Also, I can't use MongoCollection#find anymore because i'm not authorized, but this used to work as well and also, I have the permissions dbAdmin and readWrite so I should be able to do so?

Thank you for your help!

_SIM_

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, I had the permissions of dbAdmin and readWrite assigned to the admin database, which was wrong. Still strange tho that it worked before.